# ASP.NET core "create" action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am creating a web app using asp.net mvc.
I used the default scaffolding to create the controller and the view (I have user table and game table ofc database is created beforehand)
when I try to create new entity in the game table using the default create form it doesn't submit the data.
when I do the same in the user table it works fine.

the problem is that its the default code generated by visual studio and I'm not able to figure out what could be the cause.

this is the controller create action :

```
        // GET: Games/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Games/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Name,ReleaseDate,Genre,ageRestriction,Developer,Description")] Game game)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(game);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(game);
    }
```

this is the create view :

```
@model GameSense.Models.Game

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Game</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Genre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Genre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Genre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ageRestriction" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ageRestriction" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ageRestriction" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Developer" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Developer" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Developer" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

and this is the model for "game" :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GameSense.Models
{
    public class Game
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ageRestriction { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Developer { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Coordinates DeveloperLocation { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

as I said, its very "defaulty" i just want to see that everything works before i continue..
any ideas on what might be going on and why i cant create new "Game" items in the database using the default form?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what's going on?

Comment: your ID field is not inside the posted form.

Comment: @DavidStania Naturally it won't be, on a _Create_ action. The ID would be created by the database on insertion of the record.  Note that the ID field isn't required in the model. The only mistake really is putting the ID in the Bind attribute in the method signature.

Comment: @ADyson does it work after removing ID from Bind attribute?

Comment: @DavidStania possibly, I'm not sure off the top of my head without being able to quickly test it. But it's certainly redundant, at best. That's why I asked OP to provide some debugging info to narrow down the issue a bit.

Comment: @ADyson sorry! My mistake! I thought you are the OP :-)

Comment: @ADyson to be honest I'm not sure how to debug that.. vs doesnt let me use breakpoints and i cant see anything that can help me on the browser side :\
that's why I'm so struggling .. i thought there's no way to do a step-by-step like i normally do..(its my first web app)

Comment: "doesnt let me use breakpoints"...what do you mean? An error when you try to set a breakpoint or something? What about if you step through line by line? Meanwhile in the browser you can open the Developer Tools and look at the Network tool - it should show the request going to the server when you submit (you can tick "preserve log" so it stays between postbacks to make it easier), and what response you get back. The console may also contain errors if any JS or network errors occur.

Comment: Can you add some logging to your application? If debugging is not possible for some reason, we often add logging to our applications.

Comment: @ADyson i think i found the problem.. not sure how to solve it tho.. ModelState.IsValid returning false for some reason

Comment: It should tell you why if you look inside the modelstate - stop the debugger on it and you can expand the object. have you tried my earlier suggestion though and remove the "ID" from the `Bind(...)`  command?

Comment: Another reason actually could be that you've set the `Coordinates` property as Required in your model, but you aren't asking the user to enter any value(s) for that in the form. So it will always be null (and thus always fail validation).

Comment: @ADyson yes i removed it and it didnt change.. found the problem tho.. i added a location for a game(where the developers are located) and it said i cant use custom object that i created in the model so i created another model that holds the location coordinates and used that... it fails to validate the coordinates... Thank you!! you really helped ! *i saw the second comment after i commented .. *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the `Coordinates` property as `Required` in your model, but you aren't asking the user to enter any value(s) for that in the form. So it will always be null (and thus always fail validation).

You can either remove the `[Required]` attribute from the property, or remove the property from the model entirely, or build some UI to allow the field to be populated by the user.